# Revert files to a specific commit without affecting local repository git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, local

This is what I'm doing:

```
git init         // initialize repository
git add foo.bar  // adds foo.bar to the repository
git commit -m "commit message"  // commits the added files
git status  // status of repository
git log     // commit log
```

How to revert files to a specific commit without affecting repository? 
Simple use case scenario: you want to test how the program works with an older revision but keeping in the repo the later commits.

Commits id is a sha key? no number like svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You use `git commit` to add new commits.
- You use `git log` to list all commits (this will also show the SHA1 id of the commits)
- You use `git reset --hard <SHA1>` to reset your branch to a given SHA1 id
- You use `git checkout <SHA1>` to view an older commit without changing your branches.

Git has a great help. For example you can use `git help reset` for details about `git reset`.

Use `gitk --all` or `git log --graph --decorate --all` for a good overview over the current situation.

Comment: For testing purposes: I have a repo with one file commited. Modify the file and commit again. The I do `git reset --hard <commit 1 sha1>` it works, file gets reverted BUT my second commit is deleted from log. Is it possible to revert to a previous commit without loosing log history? I'll be reading git help meanwhile

Comment: `git checkout <commit 1 sha1>` behaves the same way

Comment: There is also `git revert` which adds another commit reverting a previous commit. `git checkout` does not change your branch, it will only show you the content of that commit. Have a look at `gitk --all` to see what is going on.

Comment: That works, it's weird that generates a commit. I guess I have to make use of branches to achieve what I want in a git way.

Comment: I am still not sure, what exactly you want. If you do not like a change introduced by some commit, either remove that commit or add a new commit undoing those changes.

Comment: Sometimes I want to go back to a specific revision to test how stuff works in that revision. That doesn't mean that later commits are wrong.

Comment: In this case `git checkout <sha1>` is the right thing to do. You can checkout an older commit work on it and switch back with something like `git checkout master`.

Comment: oh I see! it does not remove the later commits. I have 2 commits, then `git checkout <sha1 first commit>` then `git log` only shows first commit. But `git checkout master` brings the second commit. Awesome, this is what I needed. I'll update the question and if you want put that last comment in the answer. I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can *reset* the last commit through: `git reset HEAD~1`.

Yes, git uses SHA1 hashes for commit IDs.

Comment: `git reset HEAD~1` removes my last commit but it doesn't revert files to the previous commit state, it leaves those changes unstaged.